# Sort column headers in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I add columns in datagridview for particular row in my table.By select command in sql.using this code

```
foreach (DataRow rowCol in dsCol.Tables["Columns"].Rows)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(rowCol["Price"].ToString() + " - City");
    dt.Columns.Add(rowCol["Price"].ToString() + "  - Country");
}
```

Data Grid Shows columns in order **Apple-City|Apple-Country|Banana-City|Banana-Country**
MY need is **Apple-City|Banana-City|Apple-Country|Banana-Country**
How can i sort the first row(Headers)in Datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over your columns twice, like this:

```
foreach (DataRow rowCol in dsCol.Tables["Columns"].Rows.OrderBy(x => x["Price"].ToString()))
    dt.Columns.Add(rowCol["Price"].ToString() + " - City");

foreach (DataRow rowCol in dsCol.Tables["Columns"].Rows.OrderBy(x => x["Price"].ToString()))
   dt.Columns.Add(rowCol["Price"].ToString() + "  - Country");
```

Please note that the OrderBy is a Linq methods, so you have to be using C# 3.0 or newer for this to work and also add the linq references. Also, maybe you should consider using the Entity framework.

Comment: i did the same thing. but is there any way to sort the headers

Comment: I revised the answer to sort entries. Please note that you should refactor the code above into something better. I wrote that just to show you the way to do what you wanted.